# Writing a set of all even numbers inside given interval.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's i have sets E = {x ∈ N | x even} and L = {x ∈ N | x ≥ 3}
If i wanted to write a intersection of these sets, would writing

> { 2x : x ∈ N| x ≥ 3}

Be correct way to do it?

Comment: @amWhy Thank you,didn't notice it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it wouldn't.  You should write something like $\{ x \in \mathbb{N} | x \equiv 0 \mod 2  \wedge x  \geq 3 \} $.  When you are createing the intersection of sets you and the conditions together.

Comment: wouldn't it be x mod2 = 0 ^ x ≥ 3 ?

Comment: @August They are two ways of expressing the same thing.

Comment: Oh i see now,thank you